# Rails Self Joins One Join Table for More than One Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, self-join

There are many answers to the question of implementing a simple self-join in Rails. My problem is a bit complex.

I have many models. Doctor, Clinic, Treatment etc. A doctor can have similar doctors. A clinic can have similar clinics and so on. I can implement separate self joins for each model but this will lead to repetition of code. Is there a way to have one table to self join different models? I think the solution lies with using polymorphic association either on the join table or as an intermediate table but I can't seem to come up with a working code.

Comment: Add your models, example data and the expected output of a query. That makes your problem easier to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Just say no to polymorphic associations. Yeah they let you cheat the relational database model and are good for those special cases where you have a "behavior" that needs to be shared with a ton of different classes. Like in libraries. In reality though there is nothing you can do with polymorphic assocations that can't be done (arguably better) with more columns / tables.

The biggest con is that polymorphic associations don't have any real foreign keys in the database. That means the database does not guarantee referential integrity. There are also tons of issues related to joining, eager loading and the fact that its a leaky abstraction like when it comes to for example ordering.

Code duplication should really be a secondary concern compared to a good solid database design or the single responsibility principle. You should also consider the fact that joins are not just plumbing. In many cases the join table is an entity in itself and describes the relations between entities. Like you might actually want to keep track of how long a doctor worked at a clinic. If you build your mega do everything polymorphic join table (and your god class join model) you will have to redesign it anyways when the requirements change.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. They are worth pondering over.